# Is there a way to swap webform object between nodes?

Tags: webforms

I have a weird situation.

[Webform Localization](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_localization) module allows localization by string translation. That's good, that's what I wanted to use. Sadly, it treats all strings as if their "original" language was English. That's a limit/bug I can live with, but one of my editors created webform under node in another language. I can't simply change node's language, because it's title etc are set up OK. Or rather, I can, but I'll have enough work with [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) already that I want to avoid it.

Is there a way to connect that webform to English node, and connect empty webfrom from English node to this one? i only need to do it once, so it doesn't need to be pretty.

Simply swapping Node IDs in `{webform}` table does not help. It swaps confirmation messages etc (but these i would prefer to leave where they are), but does not swap actual webform components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply swapping Node IDs in `{webform}` table does not help, but switching them in `{webform_component}` is.

The way I did it was to swap nids in following tables:

- `{webform}`
- `{webform_component}`
- `{webform_emails}`

I didn't touch submission tables because I was planning to purge them anyway, but for test purposes I needed to swap:

- `{webform_submissions}`
- `{webform_submitted_data}`

That did it. Don't know if it is really enough, but I see no errors after a long time of use.